# Appending Table with input from arrays in Google apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have been trying to add a function to an add-on that will create a table at the end of the document.

The button text is defined in the HTML as:

```
<button onclick="google.script.run.chronTable()">In Order</button>
```

The function in the .gs file is as follows:

```
function chronTable() {

  var body = DocumentApp().getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var chronTable = body.appendTable();

    //Create 5 rows and 4 columns
  for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    var tr = chronTable.appendTableRow();
    }
    //add 4 cells in each row
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
      var td = tr.appendTableCell('Cell '+i+j);
    }
}
```

In the end, I want to insert text that I've defined in an earlier function that applies attributes to text with a button in the HTML, and which I've stored in an array as follows:

```
function highlightStyleRed() {

  //App>Doc>Body>Paragraph>Text
  //selection>rangeElements>RangeElement>Element>Text

  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {

//declare variables once before loop
var elements = selection.getRangeElements();    
var rngEelement;
var element;
var text;
var startOffset;
var endOffsetInclusive;
var redSelected = []; // creates array for export to appended table

//loop through selection
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
  rngElement = elements[i];
  element = rngElement.getElement();
  if (element) {
    text = element.asText();  
    if (text) {
      //if we are on a 'partial element' we need to only grab the selected part of the text
      if (rngElement.isPartial()) {
        startOffset = rngElement.getStartOffset();
        endOffsetInclusive = rngElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        text.setBackgroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, '#ff3333');
        redSelected.push(text);//pushes text to array

      } else {
        text.setBackgroundColor('#ff3333');
        redSelected.push(text);//pushes text to array

      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
  }

So far, I can't even get the table to show up. Is there something missing in this code?

Also, when I try to declare the array and insert the array into a table cell, it isn't recognized. Can I declare an array created in a different function?

Answer (score 0):

On your first code you would have to put the for loop inside the other for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    var tr = chronTable.appendTableRow();

    //add 4 cells in each row
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
      var td = tr.appendTableCell('Cell '+i+j);
    }
}
```

With the previous code, it created a table but created an error in the Doc.

For the second part of your issue, i'm not sure what is what you tried to do. Could you explain a little bit? or give an example.